# Quais são as vantagens e desvantagens de desenvolver ou não com Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, xamarin

Utilizando tecnologias como Xamarin, é possível, com algumas alterações, desenvolver um mesmo aplicativo para várias plataformas tendo um grande reaproveitamento de código. Já, com o Android Studio, é possível desenvolver aplicativos exclusivamente para Android, que disponibiliza algumas funcionalidades exclusivas para tal.

Conversando sobre isso com um amigo, ele me disse, porém, que algumas funcionalidades são mais precárias ou até mesmo inexistentes usando esse tipo de tecnologia (ele também mencionou Ionic).

Que funcionalidades são perdidas? Quão impactante isso é no meu app? Há mais alguma desvantagem?

Answer (score 0):

Ao desenvolver um aplicativo com essas tecnologias que você citou a principal desvantagem é com relação a performance. Por mais que estejam em constante evolução, sempre existe uma camada a mais sobre o android, o que não ocorre ao desenvolver o aplicativo nativo.
Claro que o nativo por si só não garante performance, uma implementação mau feita no nativo pode ser mais lento que uma bem feita em um hibrido por exemplo.

Answer (score -1):

Uma ferramenta que também funciona como o xamarin, só que usando java, é a [Totalcross](http://www.totalcross.com) e a vantagem dela sobre o xamarin ou Ionic é que não tem perda de performance, em alguns casos, tem-se é ganho.